# SwiftUI passing touch events from UIViewControllerRepresentable to View behind

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, touch, swiftui

I'm working on a project which uses a mixture of UIKit and SwiftUI. I currently have a ZStack which I hold my SwiftUI content in, I need to display a UIViewController over top of that content. So the last item in my ZStack is a UIViewControllerRepresentable. ie:

```
ZStack {
   ...
   SwiftUIContent
   ...
   MyUIViewControllerRepresentative() 
}
```

My overlaid UIViewControllerRepresentative is a container for other UIViewControllers. Those child view controllers don't always need to take up the full screen, so the UIViewControllerRepresentative has a transparent background so the user can interact with the SwiftUI content behind.

The problem I'm facing is that the UIViewControllerRepresentative blocks all touch events from reaching the SwiftUI content.

I've tried overriding the UIViewControllers views hit test like so:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // return nil if the touch event should propagate to the SwiftUI content
}
```

I've also event tried completely removing the touch events on the view controllers view with:

```
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Even that doesn't work.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I have also tried wrapping my view controller in UIViewRepresentable and exposing the just the view. Even with this, setting the view isUserInteractionEnabled to false didn't work.

Comment: Please use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493480/swiftui-scrollview-stops-working-in-zstack-under-rectangle-with-gradient#answer-61225965 solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I managed to come up with a solution that works.

Instead of putting the UIViewControllerRepresentable inside the ZStack, I created a custom ViewModifier which passes the content value into the UIViewControllerRepresentable. That content is then embedded within my UIViewController by wrapping it inside of a UIHostingController and adding it as a child view controller.

```
ZStack {
    ... SwiftUI content ...
}.modifier(MyUIViewControllerRepresentative)
```

Comment: Could you share more details/code for your solution? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Davido it depends on your use case, but my view modifier looks something like this:

`struct MyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        MyViewControllerRepresentative(innerSwiftUIContent: content)
    }
}`

Comment: It would be interesting to have the full implementation. Even though I understand the proposed solution in principle, I have a hard time figuring out details such as what type is `innerSwiftUIContent` supposed to be? If you could edit your answer to add more details, it could be even more helpful and appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You could use allowsHitTesting() modifier on the UIViewControllerRepresentable.

As Paul Hudson states on his website: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-taps-for-a-view-using-allowshittesting

> "If hit testing is disallowed for a view, any taps automatically continue through the view on to whatever is behind."

```
ZStack {
   ...
   SwiftUIContent
   ...
   MyUIViewControllerRepresentative()
       .allowsHitTesting(false)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not *necessarily* work. I have a SwiftUI view layered on top of a SpriteKit `SKScene` presented via `SpriteView`. The SwiftUI view on top intercepts touches, even when using `allowsHitTesting(false)` and `disabled(true)`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've found was to pass my SwiftUI view down to the overlaid `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

What makes it possible is to make all entities involved generic and using `@ViewBuilder` in your representable.

It's possible to make this even cleaner by using a View Modifier instead of wrapping your content in the representable.

###### ContentView

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewControllerRepresentable {
            Text("SwiftUI Content")
        }
    }
}
```

###### UIViewControllerRepresentable

```swift
struct ViewControllerRepresentable<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @ViewBuilder let content: Content

    typealias UIViewControllerType = ViewController<Content>


    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> BottomSheetViewController<Content> {
        ViewController<Content>(content: UIHostingController(rootView: content))
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController<Content>, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

###### UIViewController

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

final class ViewController<Content: View>: UIViewController {

    private let content: UIHostingController<Content>

    init(content: UIHostingController<Content>) {
        self.content = content
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        setupLayout()
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        addChild(content)
        view.addSubview(content.view)
        content.didMove(toParent: self)

        // Here you can add UIKit views above your SwiftUI content while keeping it interactive

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            content.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            content.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            content.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            content.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```