# ScrollView with mask overlay blocks scrolling

Tags: swift, swiftui

In this example I want to have a **cornerRadius around the things in the Scrollview** but only **around the scrolling frame**. The Content should have a little bit room on the sides. This is why I need a mask, because although there is room on the sides I want that the **scrolling indicators are still on the screen edges**. When creating the mask which is a Rectangle with a hole of a rounded Rectangle this **frame blocks the scrolling**. I placed allowishittesting(false) after the GeometryReader, which didnt work. Is there a workaround?

```
struct ContentView: View{
    let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<10){i in
                Text("Hello")
                    .frame(width: width*0.9,height: 50)
                    .background(Rectangle().fill(Color(UIColor.systemGray6)))
            }
            .frame(width: width)
        }
        .frame(width: width*0.9)
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader{geo in
                Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                    .mask(
                        HoleShapeMask(
                            in: geo.frame(in:.local)).fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground),style: FillStyle(eoFill: true))
                    )
            }
            .allowsHitTesting(false)     //<--------------
        )
        .frame(height: 300)
    }
}


func HoleShapeMask(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var shape = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
    shape.addPath(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).path(in: rect))
    return shape
}
```

Comment: That modifier _is_ making it work, for me. Xcode 13b5, iOS 15 simulator

Comment: Ok I have Xcode 12.x

Comment: I find it odd that Xcode might be the issue, but it's worth a try if it's different for us (and I'm not misunderstanding the issue). With the modifier, I can now scroll through the "Hello"s which I couldn't without it.

Comment: Perhaps a bug fix with SwiftUI 3?

Comment: Please try run it in a _new_ empty project, and see if things are different (to try isolate the issue)

Comment: I'm not really following - It would be helpful if you could attach a diagram/mockup of what you want

Comment: @aheze I'll just input what I think this means, but OP feel free to correct me if I was misunderstanding: `.cornerRadius(10)` can't be applied, because of the inherent clipping, it causes the scroll indicators to no longer show. So a `mask` was used, to achieve the same affect, but the scroll indicators are now still visible again. They are saying that (because of the overlay) they can no longer scroll in the `ScrollView`. For me, the `.allowsHitTesting(false)` modifier _does_ work (see previous discussion). Hope that cleared it up a bit

Comment: Im at the cell phone so I can’t try it, but what you said is right. Because of the things inside the scrollview have padding at the sides, a clipping would make the indicators invisible at the sides, because I want that the indicator is still at the screen edge. It’s only a little design thing but I wonder why the modifier doesn’t work in my Xcode version. Perhaps I should try to use a uiviewrepresentable to try to disable the hittesting

Comment: I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68448681/15445779 
If the scrollview gets updated with longer content the update method should be modified.